# How to pass arguments from the setState updater to the setState callback

Tags: reactjs

I want to do something like this

```js
this.setState(prevState => {
  //some logic
  let bar = foo();
  return {stateElem};
}, (bar) => {
  //more logic
}
```

So how can I pass the value of var from the updater to the callback?

Comment: You can't. It's locally scoped to that first callback.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is the use case?

Comment: @trixn Yeah sry changed it to `bar`. That was embarrasing. I wrote the code directly in the SO using backticks and somehow messed it up. Anyways, I want to set the `bar` with some function I call using the elements in the prevState as arguments and then want to pass that to my main function using resolve, since I wrap my whole `this.setState` in a `Promise`.

Comment: @Vaibhav_M But what is the use case in general terms? That seems to be a quite unusual pattern when working with react.